# Host a non service wf in IIS

Tags: workflow-foundation

I want to Host a non-service wf in IIS. I read about this in MSDN in this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729688(v=vs.110).aspx.
But I am facing a problem with the structure of solution proposed in MSDN example.
I create a VS2013 solution, add a class library project named "shared", and a WCF workflow service application project, but I don't know the type of the third project described in the link named "CreationEndpoint".

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the CreationEndpointClient?  That application in the article is a Console Application, which should run from the Console.  Debug mode opens a console window automatically when you run the project.

Comment: thank you for reaply but i talk about the part when talking about "Create a standard endpoint element to allow you to configure the WorkflowCreationEndpoint"  the CreationEndpoint project .